# Receber nome do formulário ou submit PHP

Tags: php, post

Como posso receber em uma função de outra página o nome do formulário ou so submit enviado através de POST?

```
<form class="form-inline" name="indicador" method="post" action="funcoes/indicadores.php" >

   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme" name="indicador">Atualizar</button>

</form>
```

O name="" que vou utilizar será dinâmico, e quando receber o POST na página funcoes/indicadores.php quero saber qual o nome do POST ou SUBMIT...

Comment: no seu exemplo o formulário e o botão tem o mesmo `name`, você pode descrever melhor qual o problema? [Edite a pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/96561/edit) e adicione mais detalhes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pegar o nome do formulário não é possível.
Acho mais fácil colocar um campo hidden, com o nome do formulário, ai você pega por esse campo, ou também pegar o name ou value do botão submit.

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro utilizar um campo hidden, este tipo de campo fica invisível para o usuário, ou seja, não aparecerá na tela.

Exemplo:

Neste caso, você coloca o valor dinâmico no atributo "value" do input.
Ai para pegar esse valor através do POST, basta usar:

$valorDinamico = $_POST['exemplo'];

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: desculpa, faltou o exemplo do input:
<input type="hidden" name="exemplo" value="valorDinamico">

Comment: Correto. Obrigado